# How to obtain FB user id that is valid for messenger link

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

There are a lot of ways how I we can get FB user id`s but the question is not about that.

I have implemented facebook login and retrieved user id many time. So far I was concerned only with authorizing users so I used user id to mach it against my database.

However know I need to use this id to created a link to users facebook profile. Dead simple:

```
'https://www.facebook.com/'+id
```

However when I tried to link to users messenger acount:

```
'https://www.facebook.com/messages/t/'+id
```

the link is broken.

When using tools like [findmyfbid.com](https://findmyfbid.com) I can get user id whichs differs from one that I obtained from Facebook login. And this id works well for both FB profile and messenger links.

My question is - how to obtain (if it is even possible) that id in order to create a working messenger link.

Here is code example that I used to obtain facebook id from facebook login:

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '{app-id}',
  'app_secret' => '{app-secret}',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
  ]);

try {
  // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
  $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name', '{access-token}');
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

$user = $response->getGraphUser();

echo 'Name: ' . $user['id'];
```

Comment: You can't. The ID you get is an app scoped user ID. There is no way to get the global ID.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible because if it as, it would be abused by spammers. Facebook protects against it.

Comment: Kind of seems logical. But can I use id obtained from Facebook web login to point to users profile? Well it works for me now, but can I rely on that this link will work?